# Need to delete only IP address form AWS WAF IP-set using cmd

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface, web-application-firewall

Im using a CLI cmd to delete a IP address from AWS WAF IP-set, but the cmd deleting a whole IP-sets, I just need to delete a IP address not Ip-sets, give me a solution for this, I need this very emergency, I have hope I will get the solution from stack overflow frnds.

```
 aws wafv2 delete-ip-set --name sam_pro --scope REGIONAL --id c3a24360-4f25-4399-aac5-c4967b451492 --lock-token f38b26a3-e3a0-4575-a3e7-4b2b74752dad
```

Comment: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/waf/update-rule.html

Comment: U provided link for WAF, I using WAFv2.

Comment: NO one know the answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete individual IP within a IP set, you have to update the entire set with the IP you want to remove. It's structured in JSON. The command `delete-ip-set` deletes entire set, not individual IP.